# Iterator type returned by set2.begin()

Tags: c++, iterator

In a quizz question I thought the following program would not compile because I expected the iterator type to be `set<int>::iterator` instead of `set<int, int>::iterator`.

I can compile the following program successfully in C++98, C++11 and C++14 and it prints a result `9 5 4 3 2 1 0 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 9,`. It seems that the program is correct.

**Why is the iterator type `set<int, int>::iterator` acceptable on that line ?**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>
using namespace std;

int main(){
        int mynumbers[] =        { 3, 9, 0, 2, 1, 4, 5 };
        vector<int>        v(mynumbers, mynumbers+7);
        set<int> set1(v.begin(),v.end());
        set<int, greater<int> > set2(v.begin(), v.end());

        // 
        // The following iterator type compiles. Why is that so ?
        // 
        for(set<int, int>::iterator i=set2.begin();i!= set2.end(); i++)
                cout<<*i<<" ";

        for(set<int>::iterator i=set1.begin();i!= set1.end(); i++)
                cout<<*i<<", ";
        cout<<endl;
        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why is the iterator type `set<int, int>::iterator` acceptable on that line ?

It is not. `int` is not a comparator. You are violating the standard's requirements there. The program is ill-formed.

[Some compilers](https://wandbox.org/permlink/YilV3bgC5YqLBktE) check those requirements more rigorously.

---

For reference: the correct type would be `set<int, greater<int> >::iterator`, or for C++11 and later just `auto`. `set<int>::iterator` would also be wrong.

Comment: Thank you. I convinced myself in the meantime. I was not sure because on some compilers it seems to compile and gives a result, e.g. http://cpp.sh/26stz

Comment: @Ely "It seems to work" is always a weak argument when it comes to C++, unfortunately. A lot of incorrect code "works" occasionally.